# Encode & Decode String

Tags: unicode, python-3.6, python-unicode

I've an input file which is in 'ISO-8859-1' format, and I need to encode it into UTF-8 for string comparison. I did the following

```
import chardet

def loadRawData(infile):
    rawdata = open(infile, 'rb').read() 
    return rawdata

def checkIsUtf8(data):
    result = chardet.detect(data) 
    charenc = result['encoding']
    print (charenc)
    if charenc != 'utf8' and charenc != 'utf-8':
        return [False, charenc]
    else:
        return [True, charenc]

def convertToUtf8(data, charenc):
    data = data.decode(charenc).encode("utf-8")
    return data

def loadData(infile):
    data = loadRawData(infile)
    [is_utf8, charenc] = checkIsUtf8(data)
    if not is_utf8:
        data = convertToUtf8(data, charenc)
    return data

data_1 = loadData(fin_set1)
```

However, when I trace the data with the following codes:

```
print ("Original:  Ugur \xc7etintemel")
print ("Convert to UTF-8: Ugur \xc7etintemel".encode('utf-8'))
print ("Converted: Ugur \xc3\x87etintemel")
```

I got the following results:

```
Original:  Ugur Çetintemel
b'Convert to UTF-8: Ugur \xc3\x87etintemel'
Converted: Ugur Ãetintemel
```

May I know what is the right way to perform the conversion (or trace output)?

Comment: You did it right, you just need to use `b'...'` for the last `print`.

Comment: You could save yourself some trouble by using `open(infile, 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1')`.

Comment: It's not clear what's the question. What result do you want?